# End of ListView; xaml=>ListView=>Scrolled new Event=>CodeBehind ListView_Scrolled

Tags: c#, listview, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms, uwp-xaml

By default, the list shows ten items.

It is necessary:

1. Find out if the list has scrolled to the end (reveal the end of the list) (if end of list)=>
2. Continue Iteration to show the next ten elements.

{

```cs
<ListView x:Name="ListView"
            Scrolled="ListView_Scrolled"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ListTotal}">
</ListView>
```

```cs
private void ListView_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
{           
    // what to do here (???)
    if(end of list)  // how find fin of list ???
}

*ListTotal => getAllList => Scip => Take => GetBy10* *this part works, and by default poster 10,* 

necessary
if(**the end of the list**) to continue showing the following items

//**p.s. don't pure UWP, xamarin forms - for UWP**
```

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to reinvent incremental data virtualization https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/listview-and-gridview-data-optimization#incremental-data-virtualization

Comment: thanks for the answer, I will look at the documentation that you posted and try to understand how this can be integrated // I'm DevNovice

Comment: this is a document for uwp pure, there is an equivalent for uwp - xamarin forms ? Thanks

Comment: use CollectionView instead, it has built in incremental loading

Comment: If the view collections were 100% op on UWP we could use that:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data . I have a xamarin forms application
who has an android project an ios and an uwp
shared code for all these platforms, so i use xamarin forms uwp for cross-platform application (application on xamarin included uwp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirement, you could listen `ItemAppearing` event to detect if current item is last item. then call a command to load next ten value.

```
void InfiniteListView_ItemAppearing(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
{
    var items = ItemsSource as IList;

    if (items != null && e.Item == items[items.Count - 1])
    {
        if (LoadMoreCommand != null && LoadMoreCommand.CanExecute(null))
            LoadMoreCommand.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

However, `ItemAppearing` looks does not work for UWP platform, so we need custom `ListViewRender` and detect the internal 
scrollviewer, if current vertical offset is equal to the content offset. We need send call back event then load more data. For more detail please refer this david-js 's [code sample](https://github.com/david-js/XFListViewInfo).